# Rails 6 Zeitwerk unloads my class after initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zeitwerk

I am implementing a singleton class/module in Rails 6 application using Zeitwerk loader.

```
# app/lib/mynamespace/mymodel.rb

module Mynamespace
  module Mymodel
    class << self
      attr_accessor :client
    end

    def self.client
      @client ||= "default_value"
    end

    def self.client=(client)
      @client = client
    end
end
```

Singleton class is initialized in

```
# config/initializers/mymodel.rb

Mynamespace::Mymodel.client = "my_custom_value"
# Mynamespace::Mymodel.client - this returns correct value
```

Then when I use the singleton class in a controller

```
# app/controllers/mycontroller.rb

client = Mynamespace::Mymodel.client
```

it returns an empty object as it was not initialized: client == "default_value" but should be "my_custom_value".

Log shows errors

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Initialization autoloaded the constants Mynamespace::Mymodel

Autoloading during initialization is going to be an error condition in future versions of Rails.
```

How to properly configure a singleton class while using Zeitwerk ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue here is that the way Zeitwerk loads your code, it's first loading Gems from your Gemfile, then running initializers, then loading your application code, so trying to run `Mynamespace::MyModel.client`, means it has to stop what it's doing and load `app/lib/mynamespace/mymodel.rb` to load that constant, to execute `client=` on it.

This also means that if you change the `Mynamespace::MyModel` code, Rails will not be able to hot-reload the constant, because initializers don't get re-run, introducing a circular dependency lock (have you ever seen an error like "module MyModel removed from tree but still active!" or have to use `require_dependency` before using some code that should be autoloaded but isn't?). Zeitwerk attempts to fix that class of issues.

Move that code out of `config/initializers`, and into `config/application.rb`, and it will still be run on boot.

Comment: after moving the initialization code to `config/application.rb` it gives an error `uninitialized constant Mynamespace::Mymodel` and doesn't boot.

Comment: it works if placing my code in `after_initialize` block in `config/application.rb`:     `config.after_initialize do  Mynamespace::Mymodel.client = "my_custom_value"  end`. Add an example to your answer and i will accept it.

Comment: Zeitwerk will reload my class after changes in development mode and the singleton class won't work - value stored in `Mynamespace::Mymodel.client` is reset to nil after reload.

Comment: Regarding the uninitialized constant, that means you should `require` the file that holds the module definition. What do you mean by the last comment? Are you editing the code in MyModel, and expecting it to hold the value set during initialization?

Comment: i am editing the code in app's class which uses Mymodel  `class AnotherClass def bar client = Mynamespace.Mymodel.client end end`. if I edit `AnotherClass` with any new code in class, Zeitwerk unloads initialized Mymodel and `Mymodel.client` returns nil.

Comment: I wonder if this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39498710/23915 Basically, remove `MyModel` from somewhere Rails autoloads (take it out of `/app` and put in a top-level `/lib` dir or something like that, or remove it from the autoload paths with something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/59422729/23915 shows.

Comment: Let me say that Zeitwerk does not load the gems in the Gemfile (Bundler does), and does not run initializers either (Rails does manually). Zeitwerk is only responsible for _autoloadable_ code in your application (think what's under `app`), and its engine dependencies (what's under their `app`s).

Answer (score 0):

This is why referring reloadable constants has been finally forbidden in Rails 7, because it doesn't make sense and you find the hard way.

This is unrelated to Zeitwerk, it is related to logic about reloading itself.

TLDR: Since code in `app/lib` is reloadable (that is why you put it there), you need to consider that on reload the initialization has to happen again. That is accomplished with a `to_prepare` block. Please have a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-when-the-application-boots.

On the other hand, if you are good about not reloading that singleton, then you can move it to the top-level `lib` and issue a `require` for it in the initializers. (Assuming that `lib` is not in the autoload paths, which is not by default.)